# glibc ( or libc6 ) library version

Tags: c++, linux, libstdc++

I am trying to figure out what is the correlation between the version from 
"GCC->ABI Policy" and the version from ldd --version

From [ABI Policy and Guidelines](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html) I see that for my GCC **4.8.4** I should have:

```
libstdc++.so.6.0.19 <-- Is this correct ?
```

When I run ldd --version I get:

```
ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.19-0ubuntu6.3) 2.19
```

I don't understand the corelation between this two version numbers.

I would like to upgrade to a version grater then

```
2.22
```

I don't know how can I do this.
There is a way to only install a newer libstdc++ with my current GCC ?

Or I need to ugrade to a specific GCC ?

Comment: @Olaf libstdc++ is part of the GCC project.

Comment: @interjay: Just looked and to my surprise you are right. Maybe they changed that or it was false memory. I really thought it was different, at least some years ago. Thanks for pointing me at that error! Anyway, OP clearly confuses the gcc frontend, which is independent of the libs and - strictly speaking a freestanding implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libc and libstdc++ aren't the same library...

Regarding eglibc, it's an embedded version of gnu libc:
http://www.eglibc.org/home

libstdc++ is related to the gnu compiler (more specifically, the c++ compiler):
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.what

Also, to specifically address your question regarding 2.19, the last version of eglibc is 2.19:

> EGLIBC is no longer developed and such goals are now being addressed
>   directly in GLIBC.